# Is there a way to add "send mail" functinality to Drupal on a site without SMTP server?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a (testing) Drupal 6 site on a free web hosting platform, which unfortunately removed SMTP support for free hostings.

Does any one know whether there's a way to give Drupal the ability to send emails on a site without SMTP server, e.g. via the public Gmail's SMTP server? can "sendmail" help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sendmail probably won't help: If the provider is blocking sending mails on the system, there will be no `sendmail`.

- There is a [Drupal mail module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) that allows direct communication with a SMTP server; it is based on the PHPMailer library. As far as I can see though, the Drupal 6 version is still in Beta
- Libraries like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) can talk to SMTP servers directly; [here](http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/connections/smtp) is an example on how to send an E-Mail via GMail